# How to set VHDL vector size based on the log of a constant

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga

I would like to know what is corresponding VHDL code for `$clog2(DATA_WIDTH)` , for example in this line:

```
parameter DATA_OUT_WIDTH = $clog2(DATA_WIDTH)
```

and also for this sign " -: " in this example

```
if ( Pattern == In[i_count-:PATTERN_WIDTH] )
```

I will appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
constant DATA_OUT_WIDTH : positive := positive(ceil(log2(real(DATA_WIDTH))));
```

or define a clog2 function encapsulating that expression. ceil and log2 can be found in math_real

```
use ieee.math_real.all;
```

In VHDL you can just specify the full range, for example

```
foo(i_count to i_count + 7)
foo(i_count downto i_count - 7)
```

Don't use *In* as an identifier though, it's a reserved word in VHDL.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Lars example you can easily write a function for finding the ceiling log 2 to determine the number of element address 'bits' necessary for some bus width. Some vendors or verification support libraries provide one already.

The reason there isn't a predefined function in an IEEE library already is expressed in Lars answer, you tend not to use it much, you can assign the value to a constant and an expression can be cobbled together from existing functions.

**An example clog2 function**

A borrowed and converted log2 routine from IEEE package float_generic:

```
  function clog2 (A : NATURAL) return INTEGER is
    variable Y : REAL;
    variable N : INTEGER := 0;
  begin
    if  A = 1 or A = 0 then  -- trivial rejection and acceptance
      return A;
    end if;
    Y := real(A);
    while Y >= 2.0 loop
      Y := Y / 2.0;
      N := N + 1;
    end loop;
    if Y > 0.0 then
      N := N + 1;  -- round up to the nearest log2
    end if;
   return N;
  end function clog2;
```

The argument A type NATURAL prevents passing negative integer values. Rounding is strict, any remainder below 2.0 causes rounding up.

Note that because this uses REAL and uses division it's only suitable for use during analysis and elaboration. It's a pure function.

You could note Lars example:

```
constant DATA_OUT_WIDTH : positive := positive(ceil(log2(real(DATA_WIDTH))));
```

has the same constraints on use for analysis (locally static) and elaboration (globally static). REAL types are generally not supported for synthesis and floating point operations can consume lots of real estate.

**The if condition**

```
if ( Pattern == In[i_count-:PATTERN_WIDTH] )
```

Is a base index (an lsb or msb depending on ascending or descending declared bit order) and a width.

See IEEE Std 1800-2012 (SystemVerilog), 11.5.1 Vector bit-select and part-select addressing.

> An indexed part-select is given with the following syntax:
>
> ```
> logic [15:0] down_vect;  
> logic [0:15] up_vect;  
>
> down_vect[lsb_base_expr +: width_expr]  
> up_vect[msb_base_expr +: width_expr]  
> down_vect[msb_base_expr -: width_expr]  
> up_vect[lsb_base_expr -: width_expr]
> ```
>
> The msb_base_expr and lsb_base_expr shall be integer expressions, and the width_expr shall be a positive constant integer expression. Each of these expressions shall be evaluated in a self-determined context. The lsb_base_expr and msb_base_expr can vary at run time. The first two examples select bits starting at the base and ascending the bit range. The number of bits selected is equal to the width expression. The second two examples select bits starting at the base and descending the bit range.

In VHDL terms this would be a slice with bounds determined from the high index and a width by subtraction.

`PATTERN_WIDTH` can be globally static (as in a generic constant) as well as locally static (a non-deferred constant). `i_count` can be variable.

Depending on the declared range of `In` for example:

```
constant DATAWIDTH:  natural := 8;
signal In_in:        std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
```

The equivalent expression would be

```
if Pattern = In_in(i_count downto i_count - DATAWIDTH - 1) then
```

Note that if the slice length  or `i_count` is less than `DATAWIDTH - 1` you'll get a run time error. The - 1 is because In_in'RIGHT = 0.

Without providing the declarations for In (or Pattern) and DATAWIDTH a better answer can't be provided. It really wants to be re-written as VHDL friendly.

Note as Lars indicated `in` is reserved word (VHDL is not case sensitive here) and the name was changed.

Comment: I think your rounding condition should be `Y > 1.0`. `Y` is always positive, and with the current rounding condition, the function yields `2` for an input of `2`, which is not what I would expect from a `ceil(log2())` function.